# Generic Linked Lists find duplicates

Tags: linked-list

Good day all,

I am studying Bsc-IT but am having problems.
With the current covid-19 situation we have been left to basically self-study and I need someone to put me in the right direction (not give me the answer) with my code.

I must write a program called appearsTwice that receives a linked list as parameter and return another list containing all the items from the parameter list that appears twice or more in the calling list.

My code so far(am I thinking in the right direction? What must I look at?)

public MyLinkedList appearsTwice(MyLinkedList paramList)

```
{
    MyLinkedList<E> returnList = new MyLinkedList<E>(); // create an empty list
    
    Node<E> ptrThis = this.head;//Used to traverse calling list
    Node<E> ptrParam= paramList.head; //neither lists are empty

    if (paramList.head == null) // parameter list is empty
    return returnList;

    if (ptrThis == null) //Calling list is empty
    return returnList;

    for (ptrThis = head; ptrThis != null; ptrThis = ptrThis.next)
    {
        if (ptrThis == ptrThis.element)
        {
           returnList.append(ptrThis.element); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered running it from your IDE with sample input and output? Consider asking the question describing the actual problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply.  I have tried it and I think there is some problems in my for loop and even with the while loop and nested if in the while loop which does not write the data to the third list and does not detect the duplicates.  Loops was formulated from google searches I did but I cant put my finger on where the issues is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your code never iterates through the parameter list. The only node that is visited is its head node. You'll need to iterate over the parameter list for every value found in the calling list (assuming you are not allowed to use other data structures like hashsets).
- `if (ptrThis == ptrThis.element)` makes little sense: it tries to compare a node with a node *value*. In practice this will never be true, nor is it useful. You want to compare `ptrParam.element` with `ptrThis.element`, provided that you have an iteration where `ptrParam` moves along the parameter list.
- There is no `return` statement after the `for` loop...
- You need a counter to address the requirement that a match must occur at least twice.

Here is some code you could use:

```java
class MyLinkedList {
    public MyLinkedList appearsTwice(MyLinkedList paramList) {
        MyLinkedList<E> returnList = new MyLinkedList<E>();
        
        if (paramList.head == null) return returnList; // shortcut

        for (Node<E> ptrParam = paramList.head; ptrParam != null; ptrParam = ptrParam.next) {
            // For each node in the param list, count the number of occurrences, 
            //    starting from 0 
            int count = 0;
            for (Node<E> ptrThis = head; ptrThis != null; ptrThis = ptrThis.next) {
                // compare elements from both nodes
                if (ptrThis.element == ptrParam.element) {
                    count++;
                    if (count >= 2) {
                        returnList.append(ptrParam.element);
                        // no need to look further in the calling list 
                        //   for this param element
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return returnList; // always return the return list
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I unerstand where an how I must look at it properly.  Thank you for the guidance!